# Derivations: Characterization

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry

Given a smooth manifold.

*(In fact, it seems irrelevant to regard manifolds.)*

Regard germs of functions:
$$\mathcal{C}_p^\infty(M):\quad f\sim g:\iff f\restriction\equiv g\restriction$$
and the two-sided ideal:
$$\mathcal{I}_p:=\{[f]:f(p)=0\}\subseteq\mathcal{C}_p^\infty(M)$$
*(That is rather dirty notation. Sorry for that!)*

Consider derivations:
$$D:\mathcal{C}_p^\infty(M)\to\mathbb{R}:D([fg])=D([f])g(p)+f(p)D([g])$$
They vanish on constant germs and on the square of the ideal:
$$D([c1])=0\quad D([ij])=0$$

> Why is actually every such linear functional a derivation:
>   $$L([c1])=0,\,L([ij])=0\implies L([fg])=L([f])g(p)+f(p)L([g])$$

Comment: You can write every germ as a constant (the value at $p$) plus something in $\mathcal{I}_p$. Expand everything out!

Comment: @Hoot: Ah of course, thanks!! :)

Comment: @Hoot: Do you mind posting a short answer about your comment? *(I'd like to check it off.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Let me post an answer on behalf of [hoot](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/127490/hoot).*

Every function has a decomposition:
$$f\in\mathcal{C}_p^\infty(M):\quad f\sim f(p)1+(f(p)-f)$$
*(So one can reduce the problem to the constant germ and the ideal.)*